# Solving the difference equation in the stability analysis of a multistep method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

So I am confused in going from a difference equation to a linear ODE. To make this concrete let's look at the second order Adams-Bashforth method we have:
$$
Y_{n+1} = Y_n + h(\tfrac34 f_n - \tfrac12 f_{n-1})
$$
Applying a model equation $y' = \lambda y$ we get
$$
Y_{n+1} - (1 + \tfrac32 \lambda h)Y_n + \tfrac12 \lambda h Y_{n-1} = 0
$$
From here the notes say we solve the difference equation by the same way as a linear ODE. So they replace $Y_{n+1}$ with $y''$, etc. to get
$$
y'' - (1+ \tfrac32 \lambda h)y' + \tfrac12 \lambda h y = 0
$$

I am not comfortable with this step. My understanding is $Y_n$ is the numerical approximation of $y(hn)$ where the equation we have is $y' = f(x,y)$. I don't see how we are equating the first derivative one more h step away as a second derivative.

The previous example in the notes is the Euler method but in that case $Y_n = Y_0(1+\lambda h )^n$ so it makes sense that $Y_{n+1} = Y'_{n}$. But I don't see how the Adams-Bashforth gives any kind of equivalent formulation.

Thanks for your time!